# PowerShell script not moving items from variable

Tags: powershell, logging, move

I'm trying some more advanced PowerShell scripts lately, one of my colleagues asked me to make something that moves the 16 first created files from one folder to the next unless it is not empty.
I got it checking and making a list of those 16 files but I can't get it to move them to the specific folder.

Here is the code so far:

```
$OriginPath = "D:\test\files"
$DestinationPath = "D:\test\test"
$MoveNr = "16"
$MoveFiles = ""
$LogFile = "D:\test\files\Move-Log.log"
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"

# Check if Destination folder is empty.
if ((Get-ChildItem $DestinationPath -Filter *.uni | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
    # Folder is Empty
    echo 'Moved ' $TimeStamp >> $LogFile
    Write-Warning "Files are moving, one moment"
    $MoveFiles = Get-ChildItem $OriginPath -Filter *.uni |
                 Sort -Property LastWriteTime |
                 Select -First $MoveNr |
                 Out-File $LogFile
    ForEach-Object $MoveFiles | Move-Item -Path $OriginPath -Destination $DestinationPath >> $LogFile
} else {
    # Folder is not empty
    Write-Warning "Folder not empty!"
}
Write-Warning "Now back to work!"
```

It runs everything without errors but moves nothing, nor does it write in the logfile like it is supposed to, the list does get inserted tho.

Comment: two hints: 1. try adding -Verbose switch to `Move-Item` - it should output something if it actually executes
2. Use Powershell ISE to debug this script and put some breakpoints - you'll then be able to check the values of variables during execution.

Comment: Please provide code without word wrapping. Newline is effectively control character in PowerShell. You can not just insert it in arbitrary places, even more inside `-eq` token.

Comment: `$MoveFiles` will be empty because of `Out-File $LogFile`. Remove that and give it a test

Comment: Thank you Gvee and everyone else I got it to work, variable was empty indeed and logging is working now aswell ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you have used `| Out-File` on the end of the line that generates the collection of files in to `$MoveFiles`. Because `Out-File` creates no object output, that variable doesn't get populated.

Do this instead:

```
$MoveFiles = Get-ChildItem $OriginPath -Filter *.uni |
             Sort -Property LastWriteTime |
             Select -First $MoveNr
$MoveFiles | Out-File $LogFile
```

You also probably don't need `ForEach-Object` on the line after this (and your use of it is invalid), nor should you declare `-Path` in `Move-Item`, because that is coming from the pipeline. E.g:

```
$MoveFiles | Move-Item -Destination $DestinationPath
```

Should work.

The `>> $LogFile` here might be redundant as `Move-Item` doesn't generate any output.

Comment: Thank you! Was indeed being emptied in the log, working as intended now